# How to calculate average value by group and replace date in R data frame

Tags: r, date, dplyr, zoo

I have below data frame and want to calculate the average value of groups and replace the latest date of the group

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 date=c("2014-02-13","2014-02-14","2014-02-15","2017-08-21","2017-08-22","2017-08-23","2012-06-11","2012-06-12","2012-06-13"),
                 value=c(5,2,1,4,8,6,7,9,3))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date,format='%Y-%m-%d')



    group       date value
1     1 2014-02-13     5
2     1 2014-02-14     2
3     1 2014-02-15     1
4     2 2017-08-21     4
5     2 2017-08-22     8
6     2 2017-08-23     6
7     3 2012-06-11     7
8     3 2012-06-12     9
9     3 2012-06-13     3
```

I am looking for output which will remove group column and replace the latest date of a group in date column and calculate the average value of three groups i.e. the final output should be like below, where only latest dates of a group is retained in date column and average value of three groups are replaced in value column. I have morethan 3 groups and more then 3 dates in my actual data. Can someone help in finding the solution.

```
       date        value
1      2017-08-21  5.33 (Average of 5+4+7)
2      2017-08-22  6.33 (Average of 2+8+9)
3      2017-08-23  3.33 (Average of 1+6+3)
```

Comment: What are you grouping by? Your group column does not match with the average values nor with the dates...

Comment: What I want to do is, replace group 1 and 3 dates with group 2 dates because group 2 has latest dates than group 1 and 3, then remove group column and find average value by date. To elaborate, I want pick the oldest date of all groups first, then replace with latest of oldest dates across groups, then find-out second smallest date across all groups and replace with latest of second oldest across all groups.. so on... once it is done, average the value for each date in date column. I hope it is clear. Sorry if it is still confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to achieve this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(ind = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate(date = max(date)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date       value
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2017-08-21  5.33
# 2 2017-08-22  6.33
# 3 2017-08-23  3.33
```

#### Step-by-step and explanation

The solution becomes a little bit clearer if we see what's done step by step:
First I group the data by group, arrange them by date, and add an indicator column which tells me what's the latest date.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(ind = 1:n())

df1
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group date       value   ind
#   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <int>
# 1     3 2012-06-11     7     1
# 2     3 2012-06-12     9     2
# 3     3 2012-06-13     3     3
# 4     1 2014-02-13     5     1
# 5     1 2014-02-14     2     2
# 6     1 2014-02-15     1     3
# 7     2 2017-08-21     4     1
# 8     2 2017-08-22     8     2
# 9     2 2017-08-23     6     3
```

Then I change the grouping to this indicator and set the date to the maximum date.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate(date = max(date)) 

df2
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ind [3]
#   group date       value   ind
#   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <int>
# 1     3 2017-08-21     7     1
# 2     3 2017-08-22     9     2
# 3     3 2017-08-23     3     3
# 4     1 2017-08-21     5     1
# 5     1 2017-08-22     2     2
# 6     1 2017-08-23     1     3
# 7     2 2017-08-21     4     1
# 8     2 2017-08-22     8     2
# 9     2 2017-08-23     6     3
```

Finally, I group by date and summarize the values by calculating the mean.

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date       value
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2017-08-21  5.33
# 2 2017-08-22  6.33
# 3 2017-08-23  3.33
```